# content not showing up inside MAIN, I don't think it's a react error, more like HTML

Tags: html, css, reactjs

This is probably a dumb question, but everything was rendering and showing up fine on the browser but when I tried to add content INSIDE the pink MAIN box, nothing shows up.

This is just practice using React CSS. I think something is wrong with MAIN but I can't seem to pinpoint what.

**app.js:**

[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0V0c.png)
**Subcontents.js:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styles from './Subcontents.module.css';

class Subcontents extends Component {
    render() {
        return <h3 className = {styles.subcontents}>Subcontents</h3>
    }
}

export default Subcontents;
```

**Subcontents.module.css** (ignore naming convention, that's not an issue right now):

```
.subcontents{
background-color: purple;
padding-left: 5%;

}
```

Please make this answer as simple as possible. I am still learning react.

Comment: Your code seems correct, can you post a live demo on codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-wright-dzkhv let me know if that works

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code [sandbox](http://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-wright-dzkhv) here is what I found

Your `Main` component returns an empty `h2` element which causes React to ignore all the elements you insert between the open and closing `Main` tags.

To fix this change the content of your `Main` component to be like this.

**Main.js**

```
                                   //Add this
return <h2 className={styles.main}>{this.props.children}</h2>;
```

This will make it that React will return all the children (elements) passed into `Main`

PS Side note it doesn't seem semantically proper to wrap all your content inside an `h2` which is essentially what you are doing by inserting all your elements inside of `Main`, just a side note.

Comment: I still seem to return an error when adding "this."

Comment: failed to compile

Comment: In which file did you make the changes?

Comment: mainly the app.js file and main.js